# why tablesorter do nothing in twig

Tags: javascript, html, twig, tablesorter

I would like to make my table to be sorted by ASC, DESC or from smallest to biggest..

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("ChampionsTable").tablesorter();
            $("#trigger-link").click(function() {
                // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column the column index starts at zero
                var sorting = [[1,1]];
                // sort on the first column
                $("ChampionsTable").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);
                // return false to stop default link action
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And my table's code

```
<table id="ChampionsTable" class="tablesorter" style="width:30%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Place</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for champ in champions %}
                            <tr>
                                <td> {{ champ.id }} </td>
                                <td>{{ champ.name }} </td>
                                <td> {{ champ.place }} </td>
                                <td> <img src="{{ champ.img }}" height="42" width="42"> </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <a href="#" id="trigger-link">sort first</a><br><br>
```

Importing files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/framework/css/themes/blue/style.css') }}" media="print, projection, screen">
    <script src="{{ asset("bundles/framework/js/tablesorter.js") }}"></script
```

>

I tried to change in JS code sorting.. but still nothing happen.. What I'm doing wrong? and how i should get icons Arrow down up and etc...

[image: My table photo]

Comment: Did you include the arrow images in the same folder as the style?

Comment: @Mottie yes I did.. after asking a question I found error in console.. so the problem was that first function was trying to do something.. and after that just start reading imported files.. so i had to change positions.. and now is all good